# Scala types and compilation

Tags: scala, shapeless

I was using shapeless tags and wrote code similar to this -

```
import shapeless.tag
import shapeless.tag.@@

object Typeplay {
  trait StringTrait
  type MyString = String @@ StringTrait

  case class StringClass(mps: MyString)
  val stringClass = StringClass(tag[StringTrait]("test"))
}
```

And this code would not compile. Scala compiler complains about the last line of code saying -

```
[error]  found   : String("test")
[error]  required: shapeless.tag.Tagged[in.bharathwrites.Typeplay.StringTrait] with String
[error]   val stringClass = StringClass(tag[StringTrait]("test"))
```

I could not understand what was I doing wrong. So I made a small change to my code -

```
import shapeless.tag
import shapeless.tag.@@

object Typeplay {
  trait StringTrait
  type MyString = String @@ StringTrait

  case class StringClass(mps: MyString)

  val stringTag = tag[StringTrait]("test")
  val stringClass = StringClass(stringTag)
}
```

Which is basically just using an explicit variable for the tagging. And this code compiles!!

How can this be? Why does the first program not compile and the second one does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that type alias confuses type inference in this case. If you provide explicit types to the `tag` method, everything works fine:

```
StringClass(tag[StringTrait][String]("test"))
```

or

```
StringClass(tag[StringTrait]("test"):String @@ StringTrait)
```

or if you declare param `StringClass` directly:

```
case class StringClass(mps: String @@ StringTrait)

StringClass(tag[StringTrait]("test"))
```

Apparently the limitation of scala compiler.

---

**UPD**.
Frankly, I can't tell what exact limitation of type inference you hit here. My search for relevant open bugs was fruitless.

Regarding the first example. Everything becomes clear if you look at the implementation of the `tag`:

```
object tag {
  def apply[U] = new Tagger[U]

  trait Tagged[U]
  type @@[+T, U] = T with Tagged[U]

  class Tagger[U] {
    def apply[T](t : T) : T @@ U = t.asInstanceOf[T @@ U]
  }
}
```

So, when you do this:

```
tag[StringTrait][String]("test")
```

You basically do this:

```
tag.apply[StringTrait].apply[String]("test")
```

Comment: Can you please shed some light on what this limitation is. Also, am perplexed on how can a value be cast to more than 1 type as you have done in your first suggestion. It works, but I dont understand how. I tried a small program to see if this works in all scenarios and it did not -

Comment: `scala> def myToString[A](s: A) = s.toString  
    myToString: [A](s: A)String  
    scala> myToString[String][Object]("hello")  
    <console>:13: error: method myToString: (s: String)String does not     take type parameters.  
       myToString[String][Object]("hello")  
                         ^
    scala> myToString[String]("hello")  
    res1: String = hello`